# Watermark text extender fails when entering the same text assigned to extender

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watermark

I have used Ajax control toolkit watermark text extender and facing the issue. When I enter the same text as assigned to water mark text extender, It shows the entered text as water mark.

Please see below the screen shot for the easier reference.

[image]

Code Inline:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPromoCode" runat="server" MaxLength="200" ToolTip="PromoCode"
    CssClass="ie7margintop5 ie8margintop5 water width305imp height35 backgroundtrans bordernone textboxtext">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender 
     ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtendertxtPromoCode" runat="server"
     WatermarkText="PromoCode" TargetControlID="txtPromoCode"  
     WatermarkCssClass="ie7margintop5 ie8margintop5 water width305imp height35 backgroundtrans bordernone textboxtext">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

Here, WatermarkText attribute of the extender is assigned "Promo Code" and entering promo code manually in textbox treats as a watermark.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra special character or simply space( ) at the end of water mark extenders text property. also update tooltip with same text.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPromoCode" runat="server" MaxLength="200" ToolTip="PromoCode&nbsp;"
    CssClass="ie7margintop5 ie8margintop5 water width305imp height35 backgroundtrans bordernone textboxtext">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender 
     ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtendertxtPromoCode" runat="server"
     WatermarkText="PromoCode&nbsp;" TargetControlID="txtPromoCode"  
     WatermarkCssClass="ie7margintop5 ie8margintop5 water width305imp height35 backgroundtrans bordernone textboxtext">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```